# Hide @ModelAttribute variables from appearing in URL? Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3 and I have the following Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="FileUploadForm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap model){
    UploadForm form = new UploadForm();
    model.addAttribute("FORM", form);
    return "FileUploadForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value="FileUploadForm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="FORM") UploadForm form,BindingResult result){
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        String filePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + form.getFile().getOriginalFilename();
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
            outputStream.write(form.getFile().getFileItem().get()); 
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println(form.getName());


             return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("success?Filepath="+filePath, true, true, false));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while saving file");
            return new ModelAndView("FileUploadForm");
        }

    }else{
        return new ModelAndView("FileUploadForm");
    }

}
```

This controller get the filepath and use to do a blast

```
@RequestMapping(value="success")
public String blasta(@ModelAttribute("Filepath") String filepath, Model model){
    Blast sb = new Blast("somepath");
    String[] blastIt = sb.blast("somepath", filepath);
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 5; i < blastIt.length; i++) {
        if(blastIt[i].startsWith("Lambda")){
            break;
        } else {
            seila.add(blastIt[i]);
            System.out.println(blastIt[i]);
        }
        model.addAttribute("RESULT", result);

    }      
    File f1 = new File(filepath);
    f1.delete();
    return "success";

}
```

Everything works fine, but I still get the filepath in the url.

```
http://localhost:8081/Ambase/success?Filepath=filePath
```

And I want this way if it's possible

```
http://localhost:8081/Ambase/success
```

Comment: why did you annotate filepath with `@ModelAttribute("Filepath")`? should you not using @PathVarible("Filepath") to get the POST/GET parameter?

Comment: also, it is impossible to redirect view with a POST request so it is impossible to hide the query path. redirection is done on the client side, not on the server.

Comment: Well, I removed the POST request, but the other one i didn't get, i use modelattribute to pass the path where the file is created to the other controller so i can use the file

Comment: if you want to use the variable passing to another controller via redirection, you should use PathVariable instead of MoldelAttribute, especially in this case where the variable is a string. Also, it is a design problem if you need to rely on a crucial information during redirection. Redirection can be ignored by client-side web browser. It is used to prevent user from repeatedly submitting the request when they hit refresh button.

Comment: So, I just need to change to pathvariable there? or i need to do something else?

Comment: you should change it to use PathVariable but that has nothing to do with this problem because you shouldn't be redirecting your request with a variable in the first place if you don't want other to see. there is no way to solve this problem easily.

Comment: Well, but I need the file path, so i can use in the other controller, i don't want to put everything in the same controller because is going to be messy

Comment: can't you create a method or call that method from your controller method and then redirect it? this was why i said it was a design problem. if you don't want user to see, then you shouldn't send it to user. using redirection means it is ok for user to see it.

Comment: You mean if i can create a method with the content into success controller and call inside where i get the filepath?

Comment: just call blasta method where you need it

Answer (score 3):

try adding this code to **servlet-config.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" />
```

Comment: In Spring 4.x.x it is `ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true"`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue you should use `RedirectAttributes`. It will add the value of filePath to the redirect view params and you can get that in the controller **blasta**.

To achieve this you need to add one more parameter in the controller function **processForm**. At the end of all the parameters add `RedirectAttributes attributes` and then add following line just above the RedirectView statement.

```
attributes.addFlashAttribute("Filepath",filePath);
```

And then you can get this attribute in the ModelMap inside **blasta** controller function.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.